# Get individual products from bundled product on a order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, backend, bundle-product

I have a bundle product and it has been ordered, so in the admin backend, the order looks like this:

[image]

How can I get to the individual skus & qtys on this bundle products?

For example, from this order, I would like to retrieve:

```
ACULSML x 1
ACPS x 1
ACFP x 1
```

So, I tried the following based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20892421/2332336):

```
$order_items = $order->getItemsCollection();
foreach ($order_items as $order_item) {
    $qtyOrdered = intval($order_item->getQtyOrdered());
    $rowTotal = floatval($order_item->getRowTotal());
    if ($order_item->getProductType() === 'bundle') {

        $store_id = $order->getStoreId();
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($store_id)->load($order_item->product_id);
        $options = Mage::getModel('bundle/option')->getResourceCollection()
                              ->setProductIdFilter($order_item->product_id)
                              ->setPositionOrder(); 
        $options->joinValues($store_id);
        $selections = $product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getSelectionsCollection($product->getTypeInstance(true)
            ->getOptionsIds($product), $product);
        foreach ($options->getItems() as $option) {
            $option_id = $option->getId();
            foreach ($selections as $selection) {
                if ($option_id === $selection->getOptionId()) {
                    echo $selection->getSku() . " x ". $selection->getSelectionQty() ."\r\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // snipped
    }
}
```

The above code doesn't seem to be working, because it is generating the following output:

```
ACULSML x 1.0000
ACFGSML x 1.0000
ACGLSML x 1.0000
ACLBSML x 1.0000
ACLSML x 1.0000
ACMGSML x 1.0000
ACDBSML x 1.0000
ACTGSML x 1.0000
ACCSML x 1.0000
ACDCSML x 1.0000
ACFP x 1.0000
ACPSL x 1.0000
```

Any idea what might be wrong? How do you get to the individual item on a bundle off an order line?

Answer (score 0):

You already have the qty. To add the sku you want to change the code for the child items to echo the sku together with the name and qty.